# How to integrate Amazon Machine learning service with Ionic-5 Angular app?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ionic5

My project is successfully initialized and connected to the cloud.
Now, How to use these commands? and How to integrate any amazon Machine learning feature like Amazon Transcribe?

Comment: You just changed the whole question. It is a completely different question now, since you specified the usage of Amplify.

Comment: Koss I have two questions , and I just added commands now

Comment: You should open up two questions then.

Comment: I rolled back the edit to the 'original' question, as per the other comments.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend creating a **Lambda Function** attached to a **API-Gateway** where you would send the data from the frontend which you want to process. In your Lambda Function you would make the call to the ML Service via the **AWS SDK**.

[More information regarding the JS / TS SDK](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/TranscribeService.html)